# Existence of a brake geodesic on a non compact Riemannian mfd

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesics

I am interested how to find a geodesic (if it exists) on a Riemann manifold s.t.

- the geodesic connects 2 different points on the edge of the manifold
- the metric is positive definite everywhere on the manifold, but cancels on its edge
- the manifold is **non compact**

**Example**:

There is a manifold $\mathcal{M}\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined as
$$\mathcal{M}=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:\,4x^{2}+y<6\right\} $$
with a metric tensor $g$ which in coordinates $(x,y)$ has the components:
$$g=\left(6-4x^{2}-y\right)\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \frac{\arctan2y}{2}\\
\frac{\arctan2y}{2} & 1
\end{array}\right].$$
As can be seen $g_{p} = 0 \, \forall p \in \partial\mathcal{M}$. I assume there is the Levi-Civita connection induced by $g$.

**Question**: Is there a *brake* geodesic which connects 2 different points of $\partial\mathcal{M}$?
$$\gamma: \mathbb{R}\to\mathcal{M}$$
$$\gamma(0), \gamma(t) \in \partial\mathcal{M} \quad \text{for some} \quad t\in\mathbb{R}.$$

**P.S.**: I've found some papers like these

- Benci - Closed geodesics for the Jacobi metric and periodic solutions of prescribed energy of natural Hamiltonian systems
- Hayashi - Periodic Solution of Classical Hamiltonian Systems

where people investigate the similar problem, but they require $\mathcal{M}$ is compact, and it looks the compactness is significant property.